# In a nutshell what's the difference from using OAuth2 request getAuthToken and getToken

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authorization, accountmanager

When deling with access token OAuth 2.0 
In a nutshell what's the difference from using:

`AccountManager.getAuthToken ("oauth2:https...userinfo.profile")`,

and using Google Plays:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope)
```

As I [understand](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) it they both produce a [challenge](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html#obtain) screen for the user,
the Google Plays screen is user friendlier. The access token can have same scope right?! 
Both call have to be asynchronously. InvalidateToken looks like it has to be checked for in both calls, and more?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I didn't know about using Google Play services for OAuth 2.0 authentication, but after taking a quick look at it, it looks pretty interesting and I think it's something I could prefer to use over the AccountManager.getAuthToken.

### Major differences

**[AccountManager.getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29)**

**Pro:**

- Can be used for all Android 2.0 devices and newer.
- Is built in to Android and doesn't require any separate SDK.
- Can be used for all types of accounts that has an authenticator, not only Google.

**Con:**

- Returns a token that may have expired so you always have to [invalidate the token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996686/authtoken-from-accountmanager-in-android-client-no-longer-working) and request it again to make sure you have a valid token.
- Requires the permissions GET_ACCOUNTS and USE_CREDENTIALS.
- Challenge screen is not user friendly for Android 2.*

**[GoogleAuthUtil.getToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)**

**Pro:**

- Always returns a [valid token](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).
- Only [requires](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html#choose) the permission GET_ACCOUNTS
- User friendly challenge screen.
- [Recommended by Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365219/in-a-nutshell-whats-the-difference-from-using-oauth2-request-getauthtoken-and-g#comment20015992_14374577)

**Con:**

- Require Android 2.2 and that the device have Google Play
- Require that you download and include the [Google Play services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) in your app.
- You need to [register your app](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) in the Google API Console
- Can "only" be used for Google services that uses OAuth 2.0

### Challenge screen comparison

[AccountManager.getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) Challenge screen on Gingerbread and Ice Cream Sandwich

[image: getAuthToken challenge screen for Gingerbread]
[image: getAuthToken challenge screen for Ice cream sandwich]

[GoogleAuthUtil.getToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) Challenge screen

[image: getToken challenge screen]
[image: getToken challenge screen, more details]

### Summary

Since the GoogleAuthUtil approach has a much user friendlier challenge screen and requires less permissions at install time I would definitely use this approach instead of the AccountManager.getAuthToken approach whenever I can. Since you always get a valid token and don't have to hassle with invalidating the token it should make the code simpler as well.

Comment: Im only reading about GoogleAuthUtil.getToken will try a sample now, nice summery you did that sums up my findings and the invalidating and random exceptions thrown by the AccountManager is terrible. I think the OAuth 2.0 support for  AccountManager.getAuthToken was "experimental" and this is the real deal maybe,

Comment: Tackar så mycket, hoppas några fler slänger in sina 5-cent i denna diskussion. Check this out by [Tim Bray](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html)

Comment: nibarius has it right.  If at all possible, the GoogleAuthUtil approach is the one to take, it’s where we’re investing all our eng efforts.

Comment: I've updated the answer with screenshots and restructured it to be easier to read. @Erik I hope you don't mind that I used your screenshots.

Comment: @nibarius which is better? **GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(...)** vs **GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)**   you can answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142641/access-to-google-api-googleaccountcredential-usingoauth2-vs-googleauthutil-get

Comment: @LOG_TAG thanks for the pointer, I gave an answer in that question.

Comment: GoogleAuthUtil.getToken doesn't always return a valid token. When my app is authorized but I revoke the access in https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions the call still returns a token but not a valid one (can be checked at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=token). There seems to be some caching involved...