# GoogleAuthUtil vs AcountManager for getting token

Tags: android, rest, authentication

Need your advice.

Can't understand clearly - when [AccountManager.getAuthToken ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) should be used and when [GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Please help make demarcation. 
I personnaly need to authentificate for AppEngine access from an Android app.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142641/access-to-google-api-googleaccountcredential-usingoauth2-vs-googleauthutil-get

Comment: First one is generic, second one is specific to google. You should use the second one if you need to authenticate against Google.

Comment: Also see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365219/in-a-nutshell-whats-the-difference-from-using-oauth2-request-getauthtoken-and-g/14374577

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now